# Display search results from search-view (in fragment) in new fragment / floating dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, searchview, searchable

I have an app with a MainActivity & Navigation drawer. I have a option **Friends** in the nav. drawer which on selecting displays a **FriendsFragment** which displays a list of friends with their other details. This fragment (support.v4.app.Fragment) has a SearchView (search menu) on the toolbar, which searches a particular friend from the friends list. I have used :

```
SearchView sv = new SearchView(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, sv);

sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

I have implemented **onQueryTextChange** in my Fragment which searches for a friend. (**from the local Arraylist which I use to populate the list**) I am displaying the search results by updating the same list-view & notifying the adapter. Now using this code, I want to display the search results in a new activity/fragment as the user types in the search-key. But for doing so, I need to pass my entire list of friends (which could be in 10,000s..) from my fragment to the Searchable activity/fragment, which I wish to avoid.

Any idea how I can achieve this. I am also ok, if I am able to display the results in a dialog floating over the FriendsFragment. I am a bit reluctant to go & search inside my db, since I already have the Arraylist populated from the database. So, I want to search within the Arraylist.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First: Why load 10,000 items into an ArrayList? Does the user scroll through that entire list every time? Shouldn't that be paged and/or in an infinite scroller? Second, when you say database, do you mean SQLite? If so, the search result should come back with significantly fewer results if you run a query with a WHERE clause filter, so re-loading a handful of results shouldn't be that bad. Or are these assumptions not correct about what you're doing?